# Why is this method still getting called after the first result is given?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm developing a MeteorJS app and I'm dynamically adding a data-target attribute for activating a modal and three of the additions are acting normal and producing correct results, yet the first target repeatedly calls the method which eats up CPU and RAM, and breaks what I'm trying to accomplish. The one fix I found is to add null/hidden tag that calls the method first but this doesn't fix the issue repeated calls that eat up CPU and RAM.

HTML:

```
{{#each getCategories}}
    <div class="row hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg visible-xs-block">
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <h2>{{this.category}}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <!--
          Must have this null element for some odd reason
          the first call to getUniqueID continuous runs and breaks
          this functionality so this a quick fix
        -->
        <!-- <null style="display:none;">{{getUniqueID}}{{getUniqueID}}</null> -->
        <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submit_{{getUniqueID}}"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        {{>cardSumbitModal category=this.category id=getUniqueID}}
      </div>
    </div>
      {{#each cards this.category}}
      <div class="row hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg visible-xs-block">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          {{>card id=_id color=../color}}
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
```

JS:

```
getUniqueID: function(){
        var id = Session.get("roomNumber");
        var count = Session.get("getUniqueID_CallCount");

        id = id + count;
        if(!Session.get("pairSet")){
            Session.set("pairSet", true);
        }else{
            count++;
            Session.set("pairSet", false);
        }
        Session.set("getUniqueID_CallCount",count);
        return id;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because helpers are designed to be *reactive* they can run much more often than you expect. You should setup the `getCategories` helper to map an array and include the unique id as a an extra column so it doesn't need to be computed with every document/row.